# IK not working properly

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

I did the exact same IK steps in two armatures and one of them `SimpleArmature` works great, but with the second one `HumanArmature`it works really bad. Each of them has an IK bone named "IK" which should control the left Arm of each armature. With the `HumanArmature` once I grab the IK bone I find it flickering and rotating and it's very hard to control. I don't know why and how I can have a better IK control in my `HumanArmature`

My blend file can be found here in this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xmcf714d0oavyh4/ik.blend?dl=0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a circular dependency: the Ik bone is moving the forearm, which is moving the ik bone, ........

Select your armature, go to edit mode and unparent the ik bone from the forearm. Then you can parent it to another bone which is not part of the IK chain.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. And do you know how I can set the max rotation of each bone in the ik chain bones? As when I use the Ik bone limits it doesn't work properly and the bone starts jiggling... Any thoughts? Like how I can set the lower arm bone to have a min-max of -30 to 30 around each axis?